SSRS Linechart with 2 lines formatting labels
I'm looking to create a graph with 2 lines and print labels of each value for both lines. I can't format it so it's readable.The labels always overlap when the two lines are too close and they place randomly. Is it possible to make the graph readable when the lines are close and the labels are positioned correctly or do you necessarily have to go through two graphs for better readability?
I tried using Smart labels option but it didn't help to format it as I need
I put a screen of the graphic below
(https://i.sstatic.net/vy542.png)
Thanks in advance for the help
